# LINQ GroupBy: Where is "into GroupName" in the Expression tree?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, iqueryable

Assuming:

```
var qry = from elem in SomeData
          group elem by elem.SomeMember into GroupName
          select new { Key = GroupName.Key.SomeMember, Count = GroupName.Count()};
```

When navigating the resulting Expression tree (`SomeData` is `IQueryable`), I see that the Expression that represents the `select` Method-Call refers to `GroupName`, however, when looking at the Expression that represents the `group by`, I can not find any mention of `GroupName` in any of its members. Where is it gone? And if it is omitted in the Expression tree, why is it gone; shouldn't it be defined before it is referred to?

Comment: When it's translated from query syntax to method syntax `GroupName` will go away completely.  As it is, it just won't exist at all; if it's used in a more complex manor it will be translated into a `Select` call that combines the group with the previous sequence.

Comment: More to the point unless of course your question is purely academic, why do you want to find groupname in the expression tree?

Comment: @PaulZahra It is required for writing a somewhat special query provider. I need to be able to, for every member of the result, follow member declarations and identifier in the Expression tree until I reach an identifier that exists outside the linq query. So for example (assuming the example above): `Key` -> `GroupName.Key.SomeMember` -> `elem.SomeMember`. For `GroupName.Key.SomeMember` I can only find the identifier (in `select`), but not the declaration of the variable `GroupName`.

Comment: This may help you resolve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599999/retrieving-an-expression-from-a-property-and-adding-it-to-an-expression-tree, Failing that perhaps listing the code you are using to attempt to retrieve groupname would be productive.